# Find shortest path in dynamic graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

Let's see our example input:

`10.01.2013 CREATE road between 1 and 2 with maximum speed 90 and distance 120 
25.03.2013 CREATE road between 1 and 4 with maximum speed 110 and distance 25 
13.07.2013 CREATE road between 2 and 3 with maximum speed 160 and distance 320
19.07.2013 MODIFY road between 1 and 4 with maximum speed 120
01.11.2013 CREATE road between 1 and 3 with maximum speed 30 and distance 34
21.11.2013 MODIFY road between 2 and 3 with maximum speed 130
30.12.2013 CREATE road between 2 and 4 with maximum speed 80 and distance 120`

When we MODIFY graph, the speed can be only improved.

Ok, and I need to answer for questions. For instance:
`When time travel between 1 and 4 will be shorter than 20 minutes 
When time travel between 2 and 4 will be shorter than 70 minutes`

Maximum number of queries is 10.

This is example, random data only for explain my problem.

I answer for this question using dijkstra algorithm, but I'm running Dijkstra for every query in every modification of graph. So if I have `10 000` modifications and `10` queries my solution will run `100 000` times Dijkstra algorithm. I know that's bad, but for this time I can't get better solution, so I'm writing here for help. I can add that maximum number of vertex is 10 000 and maximum number of edges is 100 000.

Comment: Are there any rules for `MODIFY`? In your example you always improve the speed. Can the speed go down? For example, would `19.07.2013 MODIFY road between 1 and 4 with maximum speed 1` be valid?

Comment: You need some kind of stochastic algorithm here to help you move faster in the search space. The question is really broad but I suggest you search for algorithms such as as Ant Colony Optimization, which is really suitable in shortest path and TSP - like problems. You cannot expect to achieve better complexity by applying non - stochastic methods.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Speed can only be improved.

Comment: There's also no `DELETE` rule, right?

Comment: No, only create edges and update weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since graph modifications can only improve the time of travel from point A to point B, the following observation is true:

> For modifications *m<sub>1</sub>* and *m<sub>2</sub>* such that *m<sub>1</sub>* is earlier than *m<sub>2</sub>* and travel times between the same points A and B, *T<sub>1</sub>* and *T<sub>2</sub>*, it is true that *T<sub>1</sub>* >= *T<sub>2</sub>*

This observation lets us use [*divide and conquer strategy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) (essentially, a binary search) for answering queries: pick a midpoint, find a travel time using Dijkstra's algorithm, and go right or left of the midpoint depending on the result.

Now you need to solve a problem of finding a path in a graph constructed up to a certain modification point. You can do it by augmenting each edge with a list of `{time, speed}` pairs, and get the speed by lookup in a sorted map attached to that edge.

This gives you O(q * log<sub>2</sub>m) runs of Dijkstra algorithm, where m is the number of modifications, and q is the number of queries.

Comment: What about creating new edges? If I understand what you write you will check if path is shorter than x only when we modify weight.

Comment: @John It does not matter if you create an edge or modify it; I call both of them modifications.

Comment: ok, I need to think longer about it, but I trust that it will be working when I will implement it

Comment: I'm trying to write pseudocode, but it's still difficult to me. What is midpoint? For example for first and second line of input how it will works? But big thanks for you :)

Comment: @John Think about it this way: you need to find the earliest line in the list of modifications/additions (I call them modifications for simplicity) such that the travel time is less than T. You start by looking at the graph as of `19.07.2013` (i.e. the middle of your list). If the travel time is still too high, check the range `01.11.2013..30.12.2013`. If the travel time is already low, check the range `10.01.2013..19.07.2013`. Each check divides the remaining range in half, checks the midpoint, and decides where to go next, until the range is shrunk to one point.

Comment: how can I get this time complexity? I need to edit graph in every step of binary search like method.

Comment: @John That's the trick I described in the part where I talk about augmenting the graph. Go through all updates before running your queries, and construct a graph with lists of {time,speed} pairs instead of simply {speed} values. Your implementation of Dijkstra should take an additional argument for "as of" time. When you arrive at an edge, see what's its weight based on the current time by examining the  {time,speed} pairs. Store them in a `TreeMap` for fast retrieval of the current value. If the time is earlier than the edge creation, ignore the edge.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you need just a few optimizations.
The main point here I think is that the paths can only get shorter. So for a query the answer is the first time when it's satisified.
So here's the modification I suggest.

1. You run Dijkstra on the initial graph like before.
2. Sort the updates chronologically.
3. Check if the condition is satisfied and stop if it is.
4. Pick the next update, see if you can use it to improve the minimum distance to either of the nodes using the new path.
5. If no improvement go to 4
6. If there's an improvement, push the updated node into the Dijkstra priority queue and continue running dijkstra until you empty the queue again.
7. Go to 3 and continue.

Comment: Pick the next update in the chronological order. It will link nodes x and y with some time cost (distance/speed). Check if `d[x] + new_cost < d[y]` or `d[y] + new_cost < d[x]` where `d` is the shortest distance computed so far.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that nodes of your graph is not just numbers, but numbers with dates and links also have dates. Then search thru this modified graph.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but how can I use it? So I will have two kind of weights?